# how to add custom webview client to android activity

Tags: java, android, webview, inner-classes

I have the following simple activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        wv.setWebChromeClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
}
```

I found the following code snippet for a custom webclient and want to use it in the above activity:

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.contains("mysite.com")) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I get the error:

> Error:(53, 11) error: method setWebChromeClient in class WebView
>   cannot be applied to given types; required: WebChromeClient found:
>   MainActivity.CustomWebViewClient reason: actual argument
>   MainActivity.CustomWebViewClient cannot be converted to
>   WebChromeClient by method invocation conversion

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mixed up [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and [WebChromeClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html). If you are calling `setWebChromeClient` method, argument should be derived from `WebChromeClient`, not `WebViewClient`, for `WebViewClient` you should use `setWebViewClient`.

Answer (score 0):

## WebViewClient

If you mean to use `WebViewClient` then simply replace `WebViewClient` with `WebChromeClient` and use a method that takes a `WebViewClient` object, i.e.,

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

## WebChromeClient

You'll need to extend `WebChromeClient` in your `CustomWebViewClient`.

`setWebChromeClient()` expects a `WebChromeClient` object as a parameter.

#### Change your class declerations:

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
```

to

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient {
```